# Right way to list image banners

Tags: image, html, html-lists, semantics

I would like to ask if what is the right way to use 'ul'? will it be okay to use 'ul' to list some image banners? ex. i have 3 image banners with titles and all are floated left. I use to encounter this situation every time and the approach i came up with is the first markup using 'ul'.

Is it okay to use the markup below:

```
<section class="banners">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <figure>
             <a href="#">
                  <img src="" width="" height="" alt="" />
               </a>
         </figure>
         <a href="#">title here</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <figure>
             <a href="#">
                <img src="" width="" height="" alt="" />
             </a>
         </figure>
         <a href="#">title here</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <figure>
         <a href="#">
            <img src="" width="" height="" alt="" />
         </a>
         </figure>
         <a href="#">title here</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </section>
```

or should I use:

```
   <section class="banners">
       <figure>
           <a href="#">
               <img src="" width="" height="" alt="" />
           </a>
           <figcaption>
               <a href="#">title here</a>
           </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
           <a href="#">
               <img src="" width="" height="" alt="" />
           </a>
               <figcaption>
                   <a href="#">title here</a>
               </figcaption>
         </figure>
         <figure>
           <a href="#">
               <img src="" width="" height="" alt="" />
           </a>
               <figcaption>
                   <a href="#">title here</a>
               </figcaption>
         </figure>
     </section>
```

Do they both represent semantic coding?

This is the sample of the image banner
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the HTML5 spec is so mercurial and the semantics don't seem to play a major role practically, it's hard to say.  However, based on your image, it looks like this is a navigation section.  As such, you would want to section it with `<nav>`.

`<ul>` spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element
`<figure>` spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element

I don't think that these are much help.  They are both used for grouping content.  The order does not matter for `<ul>`.

From what I've read, it seems to me that the purpose of `<figure>` is for annotations of a document -- describing related images, etc.  The spec specifically says that these could be moved elsewhere, like an appendix, but that doesn't seem to apply to your situation.

I don't think that `<figure>` is appropriate here.  Instead, use `<nav>`.  You can use the `<ul>` for styling if you need -- it doesn't provide much semantic meaning (just a somewhat generic grouping content element).

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys it really helps. Will it be okay to put image banners inside <nav>? i've read that a group of <a> should be wrap inside a <nav> does it also includes group of images wrap with <a>?

Comment: @Kreativenuts I think it's fine: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element